# The divisor function and prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

We introduce the divisor function $\sigma_1(n)$ which sums the divisors of an integer $n$ such that $n > 1$.
The question is : what are the conditions required for $n$ satisfying the following equation:

$\sigma_1(\sigma_1(n)+n) = 2\sigma_1(n)$

The answer is: the equation is satisfied when:

1. $n$ is a prime number
2. $2n+1$ is also a prime number

Then I was wondering if there exists composite numbers satisfying also the above equation.
I tested the hypothesis numerically and I found 19 composite numbers satisfying the above equation (for $n$ in range(1,10000)).

The conjecture is: there is an infinite number of composite numbers satisfying the above equation.

Is it easy to demonstrate it?

Thanks.

Comment: How can it be possible that it is a requirement that $n$ is prime, but you found two composite examples?

Comment: Sorry. The equation is satisfied when $n$ and $2n+1$ are prime but it is possible that composite numbers satisfy the equation also. I edit.

Comment: What are the 19 examples? Perhaps we can see a pattern.

Comment: (There are 131 composite examples up to $10^6$.) These are the 50 composite examples up to $100{,}000$: $329, 413, 623, 869, 979, 1819, 2585, 3107, 3173, 3197, 3887, 4235, 4997, 5771, 6149, 6187, 6443, 7409, 8399, 8759, 14429, 15323, 18515, 19019, 21181, 21413, 23989, 26491, 29749, 30355, 31043, 32623, 34009, 34177, 39737, 47321, 47845, 51389, 53311, 56419, 57227, 64133, 64325, 64657, 81453, 86563, 88915, 91699, 94259, 95615$

Comment: I agree with Greg Martin's calculations. Looking at factorizations up to $10000$, I did not see an immediate/obvious pattern.

Comment: Of the above 131 composite examples, 72 of them are of the form $pq$ where $\sigma(pq)+pq=2pq+p+q+1=rs$ ($p,q,r,s$ all prime) and $p+q=r+s$. One can show that these equalities are enough to force the desired property. I'm guessing that standard conjectures on prime values of polynomials would imply that there are infinitely many such examples (although there is a polynomial relation and not just input polynomials to worry about).

Comment: Thanks for answers. The equation can be generalized as $\sigma(k.\sigma(n)+n) = (k+1).\sigma(n)$ where $(k+1).\sigma(n)-1$ is prime.